# How to add a new folder to the directory you are in in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python and jupyter notebook, and I am writing code to save images to a folder. However, I am getting the error 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'plots/plot0.jpg'. I believe this is because I do not have a folder 'plots' in the current directory, and I was wondering how do add this. I have attached some code to see what is in the directory and how I am saving this image. Thank you!

```
img.save("plots/plot" + str(j) + ".png")
```

I ran this code:

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

and 'plots' was not in there, does this mean I need to create a new folder, and if so, how do I do that? Thank you!

'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears you are trying to save the image file to a folder named "plot" which doesn't exist. You can use `os.makedirs()` to create this "plot" folder

For example:

```py
import os
os.makedirs("plots")
```

This will create a new directory named "plots" in the current directory from which you have called this python script.

You could then check to see if the folder has been created in your directory by using `os.listdir()`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to can add a new directory without importing any modules is by using `bash/cmd` commands.

`!mkdir plot`

Adding subdirectories can be done:

`!mkdir data/plot`

In windows:

`!mkdir data\plot`

Similairly, any bash command can be run a Jupyter Notebook by adding `!` before the command.

`!cwd` or `!ls` when in a `Linux` environment and `!dir` in `Windows`.