# How can I save a file into a folder in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: csv, file, jupyter-notebook, directory, save

I'm working on a ipynb file, here I created a dataframe and converted it into a csv file. I want create this file in a particular existing folder.

For example:
df = pd.DataFrame(#Something)
df.to_csv("data.csv")

But I want create this csv file in a folder contained in the jupyter notebook i'm working on

Comment: What do you mean by "a folder contained in the jupyter notebook"?

Comment: The answer to your title question:  You'd first make the directory using Python or shell, see [the answers here to 'How to add a new folder to the directory you are in in jupyter notebook'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62785582/8508004). Then in your `df.to_csv("data.csv")` command you add in the relative path that includes the directory. Let's say your new directory was mydir, so it'd be something like `df.to_csv("mydir/data.csv")`. If you already created the `.csv` file you can similarly use Python or shell to move the file after you create the directory.